# Row Size too large Error even though it is not

Tags: mysql

Im quite new with MySQL and SQL in general now im trying to make a table with an approximate length of 31000 which is well in the limit is there something im missing?

```
CREATE TABLE gdasgds (profileName VARCHAR(255), 
profilePic VARCHAR(255), 
likes INTEGER, 
comments INTEGER, 
PostID CHAR(11), 
time BIGINT, 
type TINYINT, 
content VARCHAR(10000), 
Options VARCHAR(10000), 
Votes VARCHAR(10000));
```

Comment: The above query works fine. Describe the problem...

Comment: wich version of mysql you are using  ..

Comment: im using version 5.7.18 well i get this error when i try this

Comment: [2017-06-12 20:21:43] [42000][1118] Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs

Comment: Without checking the documentation to confirm, I am fairly certain that the row size limit is bytes, not characters; you likely have multi-byte character set for those fields.

Comment: no charset is UTF8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings.  The length can
>   be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to
>   65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions.

so check for you real version ..

anyway you can use text  for long string (or medium text or long text )

```
 CREATE TABLE gdasgds (
    profileName VARCHAR(255),
    profilePic VARCHAR(255),
    likes INTEGER,
    comments INTEGER,
    PostID CHAR(11),
    time BIGINT,
    type TINYINT,
    content text,
    Options text,
    Votes text);
```

TEXT (and BLOB ) is stored off the table with the table just having a pointer to the location of the actual storage.

VARCHAR is stored inline with the table. 
VARCHAR is faster when the size is reasonable

for my experience Even with heavy queries (100,0000 lines of text type) no significant differences are noticed.

Comment: is there a performance difference between using text and Varchar?

Comment: answer  updated .. diffrence of performance are not appreciable

Comment: well i accepted your answer still a mystery to me version is on 5.7.18 charset is utf8 is there something i need to change in the settings?

Comment: be sure for real length  .. In UTF-8, characters from the U+0000..U+10FFFF range (the UTF-16 accessible range) are encoded using sequences of 1 to 4 octets.